# Python - txt file into a list

Tags: python, list, file-io, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a file and to save the text inside as a list containing strings,
(each object in the list is a string which is one line in the text)
i only managed to print out the text line by line , and not as a list.

the text is a long list of biological stuff (random letter if you ask me (:)
and-

```
    def read_proteome ( filename ):
       f= open(filename).readlines()
       for line in f:
          print(line)
```

only printed the file (did seperated the lines..)

where did i go wrong ?
how do i set it into a list ?

Comment: Why did you accept Guillermo Bergengruen's answer instead of Martijn Pieters's?

Comment: oh, i just thought i marked all the answers.. once againg sorry for the mass, very new around here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of [`.readlines()` *is* a list](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines). Just print `f`:

```
print(f)
```

Comment: +1. To add, the variable should not be named `f`. Say, `lst` or `lines` would be better. A good name helps when thinking about the solution. A bad name leads to confusion because you later tend to think that it was chosen well and that it means what it says.

Comment: Expanding on what @pepr says: the name `f` makes people think it's a file object, because that's a common (if not very good) variable name for files. In fact, it seems like the OP confused himself, by accidentally checking the `type` of `f=open('c:/hey.txt')`, instead of `f=open('c:/hey.txt').readlines()`—a mistake that would have been much more obvious with, say, `lines=open('c:/hey.txt')`.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn Pieters already gives a simple and complete answer, but it's worth learning how to figure these things out yourself. It's usually faster, and it doesn't cost you a half-dozen downvotes.

First, the fact that you can use `for line in f:` means that `f` is obviously some kind of list-ish object, in that it can be used in a `for` loop the same way a `list` can. Technically, this means it's an "iterable".

Maybe this means it's already a `list`? If so, you're already done. If not, the `list` function takes any iterable and makes it into a `list`, so, you can just add `f = list(f)` and you're done.

How do you find out which?

Well, you can add `print(type(f))` to your code and see what it prints out. If it says `list`, you're done; if it says anything else, you need to add the conversion line `f = list(f)`.

It's often easier to do this all interactively, rather than in a script:

```
>>> f = open(filename).readlines()
>>> type(f)
list
>>> f
['first line\n', 'second line\n', 'last line\n']
```

If you break this down into pieces, you can see the types of each piece separately:

```
>>> filename = 'C:/foo.txt'
>>> type(filename)
str
>>> fileobj = open(filename)
>>> type(fileobj)
_io.TextIOWrapper
>>> lines = fileobj.readlines()
>>> type(lines)
list
```

When you put this all together in one line, `lines=open('C:/foo.txt').readlines()`, the end result is the same as if you did it in three steps—`lines` is a `list`.

But what if you can't figure something out by experimenting, because you don't know what to try?

Well, the interactive interpreter has built-in help:

```
>>> fileobj = open(filename)
>>> help(fileobject.readlines)
Help on built-in function readlines:

readlines(...)
    Return a list of lines from the stream.

    hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
    lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
    lines so far exceeds hint.
```

It says right there that it returns a `list`.

Or, you can look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/index.html). Trying to guess where `readlines` might be in 3.x is actually a bit complicated, because the type of thing `open` returns is not obvious… but you can just use the "quick search" on the left, and you'll find [`io.ioBase.readlines`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines), which gives you the same answer:

> `readlines(hint=-1)`
>
> Read and return a list of lines from the stream. hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all lines so far exceeds hint.

Comment: tahnks ! i still don't get it, i tried your suggestions , and python simply crush down , could be because the file is very long ?

Comment: @dulce.de.leche: I don't know what "crush down" means. What exactly did you do, and what exactly happened? Ideally, copy and paste from a session, just like I did above, instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: sorry for all the mass, i made a new txt file to try again , at first it did recognize f a a list , but now : 
f=open('c:/hey.txt')
f.readlines()
does return -
['hey how-are-you /n i-am-ok thankyou']

but
type(f) 
is <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> instaed of list...

Comment: @dulce.de.leche: OK, `open('c:/hey.txt')` is a file object (which, in modern Python, is called `<class _io.TextIOWrapper>`. But `open('c:/hey.txt').readlines()` is the result of calling `readlines` on a file object, which is a `list` of strings. I'll edit the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: thanks again :) hope to make a progress (not only with my program but also with learning how to comment properly)

Comment: hey ,still doesnt work :\ i tried so many option , thought this : def readProteome(filename):
    file=open(filename)
    f=file.readlines()
    print(f)
should have work , but it doesnt run

Comment: @dulce.de.leche: "It doesn't run" is not a useful comment for anyone trying to help you. Without knowing exactly what you did and what the results were, it's impossible to tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn said, .readlines() converts a file into a list and cycles through them. However, this is what I think you are trying to do.

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    print file.read().split("\n")
```

Answer (score -2):

As Martijn said, the readlines() method returns a list as said in the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) .

If what you need is to convert a string to a list use this: [ast helper](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers)

```
import ast
stringList = "{'a':'text'}"
realList = ast.literal_eval(stringList)
print realList
```

Hope this is what you need!

Comment: Note that the OP is using Python 3, but your code and documentation links are assuming Python 2.

Comment: Moreover, your example is for a dictionary, not a list, so you are only making matters more complicated here.

Comment: @GuillermoBergengruen: Well, yes, except that in your example, `realList` will not be a `list`, which means your own description is misleading, and which also means that it doesn't answer the OP's question. Also, even after the edit, this is still not legal Python 3.

Comment: Simple things should be done a simple way. The `ast` should really be used only when you really need it.